# Separate Queries Instead Multiple Where Clause in Firestore

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase, nosql, google-cloud-firestore

I want to query firebase firestore data collection with two paramaters.

**The collection:** animals

```
"animals": {
   "1": {
      "animal1": "cat",
      "animal2": "dog",
      "animal3": "",
      "animal4": ""
   },
   "2": {
      "animal1": "dog",
      "animal2": "cat",
      "animal3": "",
      "animal4": ""
   },
   "3": {
      "animal1": "cat",
      "animal2": "bird",
      "animal3": "dog",
      "animal4": ""
   },
   "4": {
      "animal1": "wolf",
      "animal2": "dog",
      "animal3": "bird",
      "animal4": ""
   },
   "5": {
      "animal1": "turtle",
      "animal2": "dog",
      "animal3": "wolf",
      "animal4": "cat"
   },
   "6": {
      "animal1": "dog",
      "animal2": "wolf",
      "animal3": "turtle",
      "animal4": "bear"
   },
   "7": {
      "animal1": "spider",
      "animal2": "beatle",
      "animal3": "butterfly",
      "animal4": "Cat"
   }
}
```

I want getting list datas that include **cat** and **dog**.
There is information [In here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries) 
**Logical OR queries. In this case, you should create a separate query for each OR condition and merge the query results in your app.**

I don't know how many separate query I need?

```
let param1 = 'cat';
let param2 = 'dog';

let query1 = db.collection('animals').where('animal1', '==', param1);
let query2 = db.collection('animals').where('animal2', '==', param1);
let query3 = db.collection('animals').where('animal3', '==', param2);
let query4 = db.collection('animals').where('animal4', '==', param3);
```

Answer (score 1):

As you have noted "you should create a separate query for each OR condition and merge the query results in your app". Since, with your data model, you have 4 fields (`animal1` to `animal4`) you will need to create 4 queries for each `param` value you want to test for.

So in case of 2 params, as follows:

```
let param1 = 'cat';
let param2 = 'dog';
```

you will have to merge the results of 2*4 queries....

There is a possibility to decrease this number if you change your data model and use an array for storing the `animal` values. You could then take advantage of the `array_contains` operator.

Proposed data model:

```
"animals": {
   "1": {
      "animalArray": 
          [
             0: "cat",
             1: "dog"
          ] 
   },
   "2": {
      "animalArray": 
          [
             0: "turtle",
             1: "dog",
             2: "wolf",
             3: "bear",
          ]
   }
   .....
}
```

With our example of two `params`, you would need two queries only, as follows:

```
let query1 = db.collection('animals').where("animalArray", "array-contains", param1);
let query2 = db.collection('animals').where("animalArray", "array-contains", param2);
```

Comment: Thank you  Renaud. The problem is my data model structure. And using array and array-contains seems better. Also 2*4 queries are very heavy for performance...